# how to add more text to be replaced java script?

Tags: javascript

im new to java script and as you can see in code i posted it replaces letter a with number 1,
im trying to add more options like to replace letter b with number 2, but i dont know how i tried adding another line of code like this `var newText = text.replace("a", "1");` but it doesnt work.

````
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function replace(){
        var text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
        var newText = text.replace("a", "1");
        document.getElementById("textarea").value = newText;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textarea"></textarea>
    <button id="button" onclick="replace();">replace</button>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: `newText` now holds the updated text, so if you want to replace more, your operation needs to be on that variable, `newText.replace`

Answer (score 1):

One way to dynamically replace letters with particular numbers would be to use a [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Syntax) callback function with `replace()` like this:

```js
function replace() {
  const textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
  const value = textarea.value;
  
  /* here we use a regular expression that matches any alphabet
     character "group". We also pass pass "replacer" callback 
     function, rather that fixed replacement string, where we 
     decide how to replace a matched character */
  textarea.value = value.replace(/([a-z])/gi, (_, character) => {

    /* use switch to decide what number character replaces current
       character */
    switch(character) {
      /* if 'a' matched, replace with '1', etc */
      case 'a': return '1';
      case 'b': return '2';

      /* add more cases for other characters here */

      default: return character;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textarea">abcd</textarea>
<button id="button" onclick="replace();">replace</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create objects with the desired values:

```js
function replace(){
  const text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
  const replaceVal = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }
  let newText = text
  Object.entries(replaceVal).forEach(val => {
    newText = newText.replace(new RegExp(val[0], 'g'), val[1])
  })
  document.getElementById("textarea").value = newText;
}
```

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will create an array based on the key/value pair of the object. You can add more values you want to replace by making more key/value pairs.

For example if you want "c" to be replaced with "3":

```js
const replaceVal = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace as a String, or a RegExp without the `g` flag, only replaces the first occurrence. Use a RegExp with the `g`lobal replacement flag.

Change

```
var newText = text.replace("a", "1");
```

to

```
var newText = text.replace(/a/g, '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

To do multiple operations, be consistent with your variables:

```
var newText = text.replace("a", "1");
newText = newText.replace("b", "2");
newText = newText.replace("c", "3");
```

Comment: If this answer helped, please be sure to [mark it as such](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)